# Openwrt: How to determine loss of lease?

Tags: networking, router, dhcp

I am connected to ISP using "IPoE" authentification.

It works this way. When a new network device is connected, it gets a local IP address (100.x.x.x) with 10 min lease, and there web authorization is required with user name and password.

After a successful authorization the router gets an internet IP with also a 10 min. lease.

When access to internet is closed, i.g. because a bill has not be paid, the wan interface gets back a 100.x.x.x. address. The access is only to internal resources.

I want to catch this kind of events by a script. It is quite easy to catch `ifup` or `ifdown` events in `hotplug.d`, but there is a problem.

In some cases when there is a problem on ISP side the lease expire, but the new address is not granted. WAN interface stays up, but without any address.

I get a log message

```
daemon.notice netifd: wan (1019): Lease lost, entering init state
```

What is a way to catch this event other that just parse logs?

Comment: Are you trying to catch this internally on the router or externally from a device? If it is internal, you could check whether the Wan address starts with 100. if it is the same IP Address you could ping it directly and respond on a reply

Comment: I try it internally. I really plan to check the IP, but first I need to catch a lease lost event. I do not want to check the IP by cron or a persistent script.

Comment: I'm not near an openwrt router to confirm this, but there, and I can't find a reference to it on chaos calmer - however, on older routers there was a file for configuring the dhclient that had a dhcclient-exit-hook that you could put a script in. It might be a place to start...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

Busybox dhcp client calls `deconfig_interface()` in `/lib/netifd/dhcp.script` in case of renew timeout.

I can add some call of a script there.